# Find file with filter path

Tags: c++, readfile

I have to set the path of the config file in some cpp files which are in different directories.
Sometime it`s require that path :

```
readFromFile("../Config/config.cfg");
```

Another time it`s require :

```
readFromFile("../../Config/config.cfg");
```

Is it possible to make something like ?:

```
readFromFile("../*/Config/config.cfg");
```

It`s not working. How to fix it?
First of all I have to set "../" to go out from basic directory.

e.g.

```
+proj
|--+conf (dir)
|  |--conf.cfg
|--+src (dir)
|  |--A.cpp
|  |--X.cpp
|--+test (dir)
|  |--+make (dir)
|  |  |--B.cpp
```

Code A.cpp and B.cpp are calling X.cpp where the path to config file is e.g.
"../conf/conf.cfg"
For A.cpp it`s ok, but B.cpp can`t find the "conf" directory.

```
1) compiling:
g++ ../SourceFiles/DBHandler.cpp ../SourceFiles/ParamServer.cpp ../SourceFiles/Functions.cpp ../SourceFiles/Main.cpp -o main && ./main
2) not compiling because of the wrong paths in DBHandler:
g++ ../../SourceFiles/Functions.cpp ../../SourceFiles/DBHandler.cpp ../DBHandlerTestSuite.cpp -o main && ./main
```

Problem with DBHandlerTestSuite.cpp there is calling the static method (singleton) from DBHandler. 
Please note '../' and '../../'.

Answer (score 0):

"current directory" is regardless of cpp file's path.. after you compile and link, you get an executable file, and the "current directory" is related to where you run the executable file.

For example: you have two file, a.cpp and b.cpp in src/. And you compile they into a.exe, in bin/

```
+proj
|--+src
|  |--a.cpp
|  |--b.cpp
|--+bin
|  |--a.exe
```

And I do this to execute a.exe:

```
cd <some dir>\proj\bin
a.exe
```

Then, the current directory is `<some dir>\proj\bin`.

---

Um, then, you need to give X.cpp about path. for example:

```
// X.cpp
void foo(const std::string &confpath)
{
    std::string conf = confpath + "conf.cfg";
    readFromFile(conf.c_str());
}

// A.cpp
foo("../conf");

// B.cpp
foo("../../conf");
```

Instead of function argument, you can use global variables, or init function, such as `InitializeXcpp(const std::string &confpath);`. (Of cource, init function should store confpath to X.cpp's static global variables.)

Comment: @andrew It is not a problem; Wherever .cpp is, "current directory" is not changed. Isn't B.cpp compiled with A.cpp and X.cpp?

Comment: Added more info above.

Comment: Ok, good but it's not as easy as it looks because I can`t make a method like
foo("../conf"); 
with parameter because the place where I want to set the path is
named getInstance(). So it`s a static method for singleton needs
and it`s not good way to make a parameter getInstance(...) method.

Comment: I throught about parameter method but in my case it is not good/nice
solution. I have to read from file in getInstance method because after
that I inicializing instance which has got references fields which have
to be inicializing on inicializing list in constructor. So that`s why 
I`m asking if it is possible to do something like?:
readFromFile("../*/Config/config.cfg");
where compilator change the '*' and find the correct path by himself.